# How can I list all users in a CRUD in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, user-management

I'm trying to get a CRUD page for usermanagement in a Blazor Server environment. I tried the following code:

The controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>>> getUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList();
    }
```

The Razor Page:

```
@page "/administration/"
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var users = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ApplicationUser>> 
        ("api/AdministrationController");
    }
}
```

The problem is that *ApplicationUser* is not recognized within the Razor view. I tried injecting *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity* but this is also not available within the Razor View on client side.

How do I get all the users in a razor view with use of a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a DTO object for your API and use that from the Blazor application.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDto>>> getUsers()
    {
        var users =  _context.Users.ToList();
        // convert ApplicationUser --> ApplicationUserDto here
        // AutoMapper/Mapster are good for this
        
    }
```

Then, in your Razor page, you can work with the DTOs:

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var userDtos = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ApplicationUserDto>> 
        ("api/AdministrationController");
    }
}
```

The DTO is a simple POCO with all the `ApplicationUser` fields you want, ie:

```
public class ApplicationUserDto
{
  public Guid Id { get; init; }
  public string Username { get; init; }
  ... etc ...
}
```